# How to deploy a Linux VM using ssh-certification on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, command-line-interface, x509certificate

i have an issue with windows azure command line interface, when i created a new vm linux using passwordless option "-P" and add the path of the .pem file as shown below

```
$ azure vm create myapimachine1 b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_2-LTS-amd64-server-20130325-en-us-30GB ahmed --location "West US" --ssh 22 -t /media/ahmed/1578-4B0E/WindowsAzure/AzureCert/mycert.pem -P
```

Azure asked me to insert the certificate with type .pfx not pem:

```
info:    Executing command vm create
+ Looking up image                                                             
+ Looking up cloud service                                                     
warn:    --location option will be ignored
+ Getting cloud service properties                                             
+ Looking up deployment                                                        
+ Retrieving storage accounts                                                  
-error:   The certificate file is invalid. The certificate file must be a Base64-encoded .pfx file.
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   vm create command failed
```

when i run the same command with .pfx certificate as shown below:

```
$ azure vm create myapimachine1 b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_2-LTS-amd64-server-20130325-en-us-30GB ahmed --location "West US" --ssh 22 -t /media/ahmed/1578-4B0E/WindowsAzure/AzureCert/mycert.pfx -P
```

Azure command line asked me to add the ssh certificate in a .pem format:

```
nfo:    Executing command vm create
+ Looking up image                                                             
+ Looking up cloud service                                                     
warn:    --location option will be ignored
+ Getting cloud service properties                                             
+ Looking up deployment                                                        
+ Retrieving storage accounts                                                  
error:   Specified SSH certificate is not in PEM format
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   vm create command failed
```

note:
this processes working correctly on Windows Azure Portal but i have this issue in REST API of python and CLI of Azure

thanks

Ahmed Abdullah

Comment: When I create mine, I'm using a .pem file just fine - the error message is a little incorrect, sorry, the server string message is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this problem too (azure cli v0.8.11)

In looking through the source code, the tool is looking for a file which begins with exactly

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with exactly `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

(from: lib/util/utils.js:34-35, 252-254 & lib/node_modules/azure_cli/vmclient.js:3448)

I suspect that a look at /media/ahmed/1578-4B0E/WindowsAzure/AzureCert/mycert.pem will reveal

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

as being and end markers, as mine does.

I found a solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/585294/convert-ec2-ssh-pem-key-to-azure-x-509-certificate), which explains what the problem is and links to [an article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/) explaining what to do to resolve the issue.

(If you're in a hurry, use the output of the command:

`openssl req -x509 -key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out myCert.pem`

instead of the naked key).